# How to store and extract images

Tags: react-native

We are having an exercise on making mobile apps. Currently, we want to render each product and have their images attached. Initially, we refer to how to save images to a folder and save their path in the DB. but the problem comes when I call the API in React which gets this binding into a variable and can't use require in the Component Image. So we are thinking about converting the image to base54 and storing it. Trouble is, this string is quite large. Can someone give me advice on solving this problem, or a link to a tutorial.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here. Can you rephrase the issue you're having and include any relevant code? You can check [ask] for examples

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.